# Calculate effect size for Wilcoxon in an existing loop

Tags: r, statistics

I am a novice/intermediate R user, who never really got into looping and writing functions. I stumbled over a nice piece of code yesterday that allows me to carry out a Wilcoxon test for my entire dataset. However I would also like it to calculate the effect size, and it seems that I am unable to add that function into the existing code. Any input you have would be greatly appreciated.

Wilcoxon loop:

```
    test.fun <- function(data, col) { 

 c1 <- combn(unique(data$group),2)
 sigs <- list()
 for(i in 1:ncol(c1)) {
    sigs[[i]] <- wilcox.test(
                   as.numeric(data[data$group == c1[1,i],col]),
                   as.numeric(data[data$group == c1[2,i],col])
                 )
    }
    names(sigs) <- paste("Group",c1[1,],"by Group",c1[2,])

 tests <- data.frame(Test=names(sigs),
                    W=unlist(lapply(sigs,function(x) x$statistic)),
                    p=unlist(lapply(sigs,function(x) x$p.value)),row.names=NULL)


 return(tests)
}
```

The function I would like to paste into this code:

```
rFromWilcox <-function(wilcoxModel, N){ 
z<- qnorm(wilcoxModel$p.value/2)
r<- z/ sqrt(N)
cat(wilcoxModel$data.name, "Effect Size, r = ", r)
}
rFromWilcox(wilcoxModel, N)
```

Thanks in advance, and let me know if there is anything else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt at combining these functions.

Please not the caveat in my profile that I am not an expert by a long shot - my motivation for answering on SO is a) interest and b) my own improvement. So please double check any results carefully before you believe it. At least it'll get you going till someone else pulls up my mistakes :).

So with that in mind:

First you should remove the `cat` line from `rFromWilcoxon`, and just replace it with `r`

Then change `test.fun` like this:

```
test.fun <- function(data, col, group = 'group') { 

     c1 <- combn(unique(data[[group]]),2)
     N  <- nrow(data) / ncol(c1)    # Calculates N assuming all groups are equal size
     sigs <- list()

     for(i in 1:ncol(c1)) {
          sigs[[i]] <- wilcox.test(
               as.numeric(data[data[[group]] == c1[1, i], col]),
               as.numeric(data[data[[group]] == c1[2, i], col])
          )
     }


     r <- lapply(sigs, function(i) rFromWilcox(i, N))    # Applies rFromWilcox function

     names(sigs) <- paste("Group",c1[1,],"by Group",c1[2,])

     tests <- data.frame(Test = names(sigs),
                         W = unlist(lapply(sigs,function(x) x$statistic)),
                         p = unlist(lapply(sigs,function(x) x$p.value)),row.names=NULL,
                         r = unlist(r))
tests
}
```

Also not that I assumed all groups are of equal size. If your groups are unequal, I think you just need to calculate `N`, and call `rFromWilcox` inside the for loop for each combination.

An extra note: in the original function you posted, the groups to be tested had to be in a column called 'group'. You can now test under a column name of your choice, eg `test.fun(iris, 1, 'Species')` will run the test on Sepal.Length by 'Species' in the `iris` dataset

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!